# Variable comparison in IF condition in Snowflake procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am using variable as comparison in IF condition like below in Snowflake Stored procedure

`if (col1=='v_f_'+trim(v_description))`

Note: v_description is an variable having some value

but getting below error, please correct me here.

`Failed: Code: undefined State: undefined Message: trim is not defined Stack Trace: undefined`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's JavaScript, so you need to call it as method:

```
if (col1=='v_f_'+v_description.trim())
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. again getting different error 'empty argument passed' , not sure if this is with the if condition.

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it as correct. For the other question, you need to share your simplified stored procedure, and how you call it. Maybe you can ask it as a new question.